# Webview goBack() issue, not redirecting to previous page after calling goBack()

Tags: javascript, java, android, kotlin, webview

**Scenario:**

1. Load **Profile page**(main URL) in WebView.
2. Then click on edit number link on Profile page which loads **Edit number page**.
3. **Edit number page** is redirected to Authentication page.
4. On **Authentication page** enter OTP and submit then redirected to **Edit number page**.
5. On **Edit number page**, Enter new number and click on submit then it shows successes message with OK button.
6. Then click on OK button redirected to **Profile page**(main URL).
7. Now if click on back button and call **webView.goBack()** then it redirected to **Authentication page** while should be redirected to **Edit number page**.

**Note:** Same behavior is happening in android emulator WebView app also
While in Chrome browser it is redirecting to the **Edit number page** (Expected Behavior).

**Expected Behavior:** After clicking on Back button it should be redirected to the **Edit Number page**.

**Observation:**

**Referral Header** was wrong after executing point 7 (**Referral Header** on **Edit Number page** should be **authentication page** URL but we are getting **Edit number page** URL).

**Expected Behavior:** After clicking on Back button it should be redirected to the **Edit Number page**.